# Static boolean is not initialized when the code is called from a test method

Tags: unit-test, class

```
public UtilClass {
    public static Boolean someBool = true;

    public static List<SomeObject> someMethod() {
        .
        .
        if(someBool) {
            // do something
        }

        return someList;
    }
}

@isTest
public TestClass {
    @isTest
    public static void testMe() {
        System.assertEquals(1, UtilClass.someMethod().size());
    }
}
```

I expected the "if block" inside someMethod() to be covered by test code, but it is not. What could be the possible reason? However, if I initialize the boolean to true explicity before calling the someMethod() in System.assertEquals() the "if block" is covered.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you are running your tests & checking your code coverage,

but when I tried the exact same code in my dev org, i got the coverage for the IF block as expected.. see the screenshot

[image]

here's the code I tried

```
public class StaticString {

    public static Boolean someBool = true;

    public static List<Contact> someMethod() {
        if(someBool) {
            List<Contact> c = new List<Contact>();
            return c;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class TestStaticString {
    @isTest
    public static void testMe() {
        System.assertEquals(1, StaticString.someMethod().size());
    }
}
```